# How an Activity can be notified of NavHostFragment child fragments attachement

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I'm having an Activity, containing a NavHostFragment with a given navigation graph (and classic child fragments). My child fragments may trigger events (declared through an interface), so they have a method setXXXlistener(Interface) to register a listener implementing the interface.

That's the Activity that may implement the interface (because it knows what to do on the events).

To do that, I was expecting the Activity.onAttachFragment method will be called when child fragments were displayed, in order to do something like :

```
public void onAttachFragment(@NonNull Fragment fragment)
{
    super.onAttachFragment(fragment);
    if( fragment instanceof OneOfMyFragment)
    {
        ((OneOfMyFragment)fragment).setXXXListener(this);
    }
}
```

but it's not the case ; onAttachFragment is called once with the NavHostFragment argument.

So I looked into the NavHostFragment, and the solution may be using NavHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager() which returns a FragmentManager, then I can do FragmentManager.addFragmentOnAttachListener(listener), so I will be able to do my own registration.

**The problem is : FragmentManager.addFragmentOnAttachListener seems to be [documented](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager#addFragmentOnAttachListener(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentOnAttachListener)) but not defined in the source file ! (At least AndroidStudio don't know it and won't compile)**

In my gradle files, I currently have those versions (but also tried with API 30) :

```
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

targetSdkVersion 29
```

and

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.2'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.2'
```

Any idea ? (to achieve my goal, or to solve the undefined error)

Comment: Addition of FragmentManager.addFragmentOnAttachListener was done in https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1316658

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.2` only depends on Fragment 1.2.4, but the `addFragmentOnAttachListener` API was added only in [Fragment 1.3.0-alpha06](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.0-alpha06). Therefore, you need to specifically add a dependency on a Fragment 1.3 version (currently, 1.3.0-rc01) if you want to use that new API:

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.2'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.2'

// Add this line
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.0-rc01'
```

Comment: Thank you ! Who could have been more helpfull than the commit's author :)

Comment: Where should be used this listener in case of navigation component? I have BottomNavigationView set up with navigation component and implement this listener in onCreate() of BaseActivity. First time that fragments onAttach() called, this listener notifies, but next time that I called onAttach() manually, listener doesn't notify. Can you help me? Thanks in advance